# Время жизни объекта, если передали ссылку его поля в статический класс

Tags: c#, .net, сборщик-мусора

Сабж. Вот код:

```
static class A
{
        static D d;
        void static Func1()
        {
                B b = new B();
                d = b.Func2();
        }
        void static Main()
        {
                Func1();
                GC.Collect();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
                //b is removed?
        }
}

class B
{
        public D d = new D();
        public D Func2()
        {
                return d;
        }
}

class D
{
}
```

Будет ли удален объект b из кучи после сборки мусора, если на одно из его полей ссылается статический объект?

Answer (score 3):

> Будет ли удален объект b из кучи после сборки мусора, если на одно из его полей ссылается статический объект?

Золотое правило. Если на объект кто-то ссылается, то он не будет удален. Т.к. время жизни статического класса ограничено временем жизни домена, то объект b будет жить пока не умрет статический класс (вместе с доменом), ссылающийся на него.

Comment: Добавлю лишь, что даже если на объект нет ни одной ссылки, это **не даёт** гарантии, что объект будет убран сборщиком мусора. Дополнительное чтение по теме: [_Все думают о сборке мусора неправильно_](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/09/10047586.aspx).

Comment: но ведь статический класс не ссылается на "b", он ссылается на "d"?

Comment: >но ведь статический класс не ссылается на "b", он ссылается на "d"?

B у вас - это класс. Следовательно, передается он всегда по ссылке. Поэтому ссылка указывает именно на b

Comment: область видимости "b" после выхода из Func1 - пропадает, и на неё больше никто не ссылается. Почему она должна жить?

Comment: Присоединюсь к @GLeBaTi, разве инстанс b не будет помечен разрешенным к сборке после выполнения A.Func1()? В результате операций поле d будет ссылаться на инстанс D, но не B.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой ответ я получил:

> "b" будет удален. Ссылка идёт не на
> поле объекта, а на объект, который
> когда-то лежал в этом поле. После
> чистки останется только объект d. Вот
> если бы в d при конструировании была
> ссылка на b, как на "родителя", то b
> бы тоже остался.